# Working on one word, dilemma using string or char array or stringbuilder?

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm, words

I am working on a **chess**(not grid). This **chess**(not grid) has X rows. 
In each of rows we have Y blocks.

I would like to know what words can I find in each of the rows. 
Also what is that's words start and stop indexes.

So my tactic for one row is:

- take all items from row (-cat--dog----) and save it to string
- operate on string's indexes using `for(...){...}`

*Is it good idea or maybe I should convert that string to char array and then operate*?

What method is faster to do that? What about StringBuilder?

@Oden thx for correction but I didn't mean grid but just a **chess** :)

---

Somewhere I wrote this question wrong. (Maybe I wrong formulated the question. It's hard to make this shape for me, so sorry.)

The main problem's question was simply included in main title of this topic. 
What method would be faster while processing over words for example `mamma--mia` (each element is ansi symbol, let say in string format)?

So I wonder if I were working on just a string it would be faster than first converting string toCharArray and work then. Or maybe using stringBuilder.

I simply ask what is faster: work or chars, strings or elements of string builder in my method.. :( What would be faster in big function/method -> that's the question.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you clarified what you mean by "a chess" here, for the benefit of the reader who may know it by another term.

Comment: +1 for explaining chess. and, if you mean chessboard, which I guess you do, what's the difference to a grid in your meaning?

Comment: chess means sequence ansi elements in rows - but not grid in meaning gridview

Comment: it is not physical, it's abstract chess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The performance bottleneck you're facing is not in the string construction, but in finding the words you're looking for. If you have *m* words you're looking for, you might end up going through the string looking for words *m* times. That's not necessary! You might try and create a huge regular expression * matching all substrings you're looking for. The way they are constructed *, they only pass the string once (basically if you start with an 'a', they're in a state that tells them "this could be a beginning to all the words beginning with a", if the next char is a 'b', state says "this could either be the beginning of a word starting with ab or the beginning of a word starting with b).

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest 

1) create an object to contain the points,

2) modularize the portions to parse the string (preferably in a class, but a method would do), 

3) then use LINQ to obtain all of the rows the the values for the column you seek

An example is as follows:

```
void Main()
{
    const string columnName = "ColumnYouSeek";

    var dgv = GetDataGridView(columnName);  
    var items = GetItems(dgv, columnName);
    // items now contains what you want
}
```

Create an object to hold your values

```
 class ItemWithIndex
 {
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int StartIndex { get; set; }
    public int EndIndex { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format(
                 "{0}: Starts at {1}, Ends at {2}", 
                 Text, StartIndex, EndIndex);
     }
 }
```

Change to below to point to your DataGridView

```
public System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView GetDataGridView(string columnName)
{
    var dgv = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
    var column = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    column.DataPropertyName = columnName;
    column.Name = columnName;
    dgv.Columns.Add(column);
    dgv.Rows.Add("-cat--dog----");
    dgv.Rows.Add("--elephant----mouse----");
    return dgv;
}
```

Modularize to get Items

```
public IEnumerable<ItemWithIndex> GetItems(
        System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dgv, string columnName)
{
    var rows = dgv.Rows.Cast<System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow>();   
    var rowData = rows.Select(x => (x.Cells[columnName].Value ?? "").ToString());
    return rowData.SelectMany(x => GetWords(x));
}
```

Modularize the portions to get the individual words

Note: This can be unit tested and refactored

```
public IEnumerable<ItemWithIndex> GetWords(string val)
{
    var index = val.IndexOf("-");
    while (index >= 0 && index + 1 < val.Length)
    {
        var startIndex = index + 1;
        var endIndex = val.IndexOf("-", startIndex);
        if (endIndex < 0)
            endIndex = val.Length - 1; // end of string
        var text = val.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
        index = endIndex;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            continue;
        yield return new ItemWithIndex
                        {
                            Text = text,
                            StartIndex = startIndex,
                            EndIndex = endIndex,
                        };
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but there was misunderstood while correcting my question. When I first wrote "chess" I mean chess not grid or datagrid, but +1 for start

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should be using either a two dimensional array of strings - `string[,]` or a jagged array (depending if each row has the same amount of blocks or not).

Another option is to use a generic list of lists - `List<List<string>>`.

Either option lets you query your data by index directly.

Comment: but what about performance list of string and char or stribuilder. Can you say something about performance char array vs.string ?

Comment: @Cooldown4seconds - They seem to be the _wrong_ choice for what you seem to be doing. `char` is too low level and `StringBuilder` has nothing to do with it.